# PHP cURL request header

Tags: php, curl, header

Somehow I can't get cURL to complete the request with the following HTTPHEADER.

```
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    ":Authority: www.*.com",
    ":Method: GET",
    ":Path: /path/",
    ":Scheme: https",
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'Accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,de;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5,sv;q=0.4',
    'Sec-fetch-mode: navigate',
    'Sec-fetch-site: none',
    'Upgrade-insecure-requests: 1',
));
```

The: before authority, method, path, and scheme seems to be the issue.

Without the: before the items I receive a 500 status without a body from the server.
With the: I get a false from cURL with the message the sending the request has failed.

Is the some escape or an other method to build the header?

Comment: I am not totally sure, but after the ':' a space is sometimes missing. Scheme begins with a ':', which seems to be incorrect, too. Afaik, all names begin with an uppercase char.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not make any difference to the outcome.

Comment: Hm.. now there are more colons at the beginning.